# why doesn't this code properly assign a new answer if a answer have unready been used

Tags: javascript, random

i am making a quiz game for a school project. i have to present on it in class in a couple of days. 
i am unsure why it isn't working.
 the problem is in determining whether a randomly generated number has been used before. the code correctly determines if a number has been used but dose not generate and use a different number when it dose. 
 any help is really really appreciated. 
here are some relevent bits of code please check the jsfiddle link for the whole thing
  thanks so much A

```
  //generates a random number
function getWord() {
    randomWord = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    alert("randomly genraten number " + randomWord);
    return randomWord;
}
```

//checks if this number is in the array

```
function ifUsed(num) {
    for (var i = 0; i < U.length; i++) {
        if (U[i] == num) {
            alert(" in array");
            ind = "true";
            return true;
        }

    }
    ind = "";
}
```

//uses the number if its not in the array its inside of a larger function

```
 if (ind == "true") {
        alert("its in the array");
        ind = "false";
        randomWord = "filler";
        getWord();
        ifUsed(getWord());
    } else {
        wordCounter = randomWord;
        deffCounter = randomWord;
        alert("word hasent been used yet");
        U.push(randomWord);
    }

 JSfiddle link   http://jsfiddle.net/ae8wp4v2/1/
```

Comment: Abstract comment: where did the meme of "quiz game as a great JavaScript programming problem" come from?

Comment: @Pointy: Abstract answer: Maybe because `alert()` and `prompt()` is a very simple I/O that is taught to every beginner (instead of some REPL thing, unfortunately)? And quizzes with control flow and data structures are only the next logical step from the `alert("Hello "+prompt("What's your name?", "World"))` :-)

Comment: @Pointy, maybe it's the same school suddenly requiring JavaScript as part of a well-rounded education, and the OP's are all art majors.

Comment: Hi i am in a big picture program. we get to choose a few electives, that we take online classes in. i took one from codecademy in javascript. at the end of the term we are required to design and complete a project, on a topic of our choice.

Comment: Also the principle of our school set out designing a quiz other students could use for SAT vocab prep as project he wanted someone to try and tackle.